# Get All instead of FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following query:

```
PromotionList dataPromotion = authenticateCustomerResponseRootObject.Response
    .AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList
    .Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("DATA"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

My `PromotionList` contains 3 objects, with `LineOfBusiness` `Data`,`Video` and third object contains `Data` too. Above query returns `PromotionList` of first object only whereas I want ALL whose LineOfBusiness is equal to Data. Why is it happening?

Comment: Because the last method in the query is `.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Uhm, if you want *all* the objects, then why did you ask for `FirstOrDefault()` then? Remove that call, isn't that what you want???

Comment: Euhm. Because you explicitly use `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Voted to close as "Needs details or clarity" because it's not been clarified why `FirstOrDefault()` was used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `FirstOrDefault` so you are returning only the first.

```
PromotionList dataPromotion = authenticateCustomerResponseRootObject.Response.AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList.Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("Data")).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want all of them just remove that call at the end and replace with a `ToList`, `ToArray` or similar that meets your needs:

```
var data = authenticateCustomerResponseRootObject.Response.AuthenticateCustomerResponse.EligiblePromotions.PromotionList.Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Equals("Data")).ToList();
```

Also as mentioned in the comments your `Where` call uses `ToUpper` then compares on a string containing lower case characters so will never return any results. You either need to remove the `ToUpper`, use a upper case string or even use ignore case:

```
Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.Equals("Data", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```